# Dependency problems after upgrade from 10.10 to 12.10

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, do-release-upgrade

After a distro upgrade from Ubuntu Server 10.10 to 12.10 I get error messages tryind to install any program.

When I run `apt-get install firefox`

My output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
firefox is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
22 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1) ...
mkdir: cannot create directory `/dev/shm': File exists
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of procps:
 procps depends on initscripts; however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing procps (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
 udev depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing udev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dmsetup:
 dmsetup depends on udev (>> 141-2); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dmsetup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of netbase:
 netbase depends on initscripts; however:
  Package initscripts is not configNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                             No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
       No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                           No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                               No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                         No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                             No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                       No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                           ured yet.
dpkg: error processing netbase (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbus:
 dbus depends on netbase (>= 4.45ubuntu3); however:
  Package netbase is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dbus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of consolekit:
 consolekit depends on dbus (>= 1.1.2); however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing consolekit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ifupdown:
 ifupdown depends on initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3); however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ifupdown (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2.2-common:
 apache2.2-common depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.
dpkg: erroNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                              No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
        No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                            No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
      No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
    r processing apache2.2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2-mpm-prefork:
 apache2-mpm-prefork depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing apache2-mpm-prefork (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2:
 apache2 depends on apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) | apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) | apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) | apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package apache2-mpm-worker is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-prefork is not configured yet.
  Package apache2-mpm-event is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-itk is not installed.
 apache2 depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing apache2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bind9:
 bind9 depends on netbase; however:
  Package netbase is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing bind9 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cryptsetup:
 cryptsetup depends on dmsetup; however:
  Package dmsetup is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing cryptsetup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssh-server:
 openssh-server depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing openssh-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of policykit-1:
 policykit-1 depends on consolekit; however:
  Package consolekit is not configured yet.
 policykit-1 depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing policykit-1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-aptdaemon:
 python-aptdaemon depends on policykit-1; however:
  Package policykit-1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aptdaemon:
 aptdaemon depends on python-aptdaemon (= 0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu9); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xul-ext-ubufox:
 xul-ext-ubufox depends on aptdaemon; however:
  Package aptdaemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing xul-ext-ubufox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdevmapper1.02.1:
 libdevmapper1.02.1 depends on dmsetup (>= 2:1.02.48-4ubuntu7.3); however:
  Package dmsetup is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libdevmapper1.02.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcryptsetup4:
 libcryptsetup4 depends on libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.36); however:
  Package libdevmapper1.02.1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libcryptsetup4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cryptsetup-bin:
 cryptsetup-bin depends on libcryptsetup4 (>= 2:1.4); however:
  Package libcryptsetup4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing cryptsetup-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
 procps
 udev
 dmsetup
 netbase
 dbus
 consolekit
 ifupdown
 apache2.2-common
 apache2-mpm-prefork
 apache2
 bind9
 cryptsetup
 openssh-server
 policykit-1
 samba
 python-aptdaemon
 aptdaemon
 xul-ext-ubufox
 libdevmapper1.02.1
 libcryptsetup4
 cryptsetup-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm quite new to Linux, so would appreciate answers being as simple as possible and explaining what is what and why.

Commands used to upgrade distro were:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade & sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

please ask for any further information needed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't upgrade from 10.10 to 12.10. You should pass for 11.04, 11.10, 12.04 LTS and then you land to 12.10.

Second, that method of upgrade is too long and complicated, and there are a bunch of things that could go wrong (actually you have reached that stage). You will need to download ~12GiB worth of updates to reach the 12.10 release.

Third, because of first and second, it will be more easy and less precarious just doing a backup of your important stuff, download the ISO for Ubuntu 13.04 or 12.04 LTS from the main page, burn it or create a live usb and install Ubuntu. There is a full guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328/169736) in how to do so.

Comment: well, for start its VPS and I went through all the updates you mentioned, backup is not needed due it is a new server so i can reinstall anytime, cons about hosting is that newest ubuntu is 10.10. Should i get another hosting which supports newer version? or.. should i get on with this and try to update every version step by step and solve the existing issues on every version to make it ready for upgrading to next version?

Comment: Actually is up to you. If you are willing to change the provider, you may do so, if you want to go trough all the updates, you may do so. Is all up to you the method.